# shell script to Output details of all the files in a folder passed as command line argument

Tags: bash, shell

So I am trying to write a script in which I will pass folder name as command line argument. The script will search a the files within that folder if it exists and output all the details. My script is as shown

```
for entry in "$1"/*
do
  data = $(stat $entry)
  echo  "${data}"
done
```

when I run it gives me following output.

```
./test.sh: line 3: data: command not found
```

I have taken the idea from here:  [Stat command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/355360/how-to-display-file-properties-via-terminal) 
Can someone help what is wrong
I have tried variations like making $entry to entry and echo $data

Comment: check your script with shellcheck.net

Comment: `find "$1" -exec stat {} \;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main issue is that you are putting space characters around the equal operator, you must remove them:

```
  data=$(stat $entry)
```

It is also good practice to pass variables between quotes in case your folder or any of the filenames contains whitespaces:

```
  data=$(stat "$entry")
```

I assume that you are storing the value into a variable because your intent is to use it into an algorithm. If you just want to call `stat` to list your files, you can simply call:

```
stat "$1"/*
```